# Facebook connection as soon as I start typing an URL

Tags: networking, google-chrome, security, facebook

This issue may be related to [Strange entries in Netstat output](https://superuser.com/questions/1190953/strange-entries-in-netstat-output), however, I haven't found any explanation or fix and nobody has even touched the base of the issue.

As soon as I open my chrome browser and start typing `f...` into urlbar, I instantly get a TCP connection to `edge-star-mini-shv-01-vie1.facebook.com` and then it opens 5 other concurrent connections.

What is going on? Is chrome prefetching something from Facebook right when suggesting websites for me? If so, isn't it strange that this opens  6 concurrent connections to facebook.com?

What makes this really strange is that this happens with NO other domains than Facebook ones when Google Chrome suggests me URLs as I start typing other things.

[image]

Comment: Any extensions in Chrome that might be "helping"?

Comment: WOW! It is good practice to monitor networks sometime. Possible solution: 1. Remove the FB thumbnail in `about:newtab` page 2. Disable auto-search/auto-url-prediction feature 3. Try incognito mode. 4. Clean all cache. 5. install & uninstall extension.